# Unable to connect to Sql Server from Docker Django

Tags: sql-server, django, docker

i'm trying to connect my Django to en existing legacy MS SQL database.

When im trying to run a sql on the database works fine:

```
sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + db_name + '.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES'
connection_string = "driver=FreeTDS;server={};PORT={} database={};UID={};PWD={};TDS_Version=8.0;".format(db_host, db_port, db_name, db_user, db_password)
conn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string, autocommit=True)
for row in cursor.fetchall():
  print(row)
```

And i can see all the tables but when try to generate model from database running this command:

```
python manage.py inspectdb --database pirineos > pirineos_models.py
```

I get the error:

```
django.db.utils.Error: ('08001', '[08001] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

This are my project files.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y unixodbc unixodbc-dev tdsodbc freetds-common freetds-bin freetds-dev && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN mkdir /djangonoguero
COPY ./project /djangonoguero/
COPY ./requirements.txt /djangonoguero/
ADD odbcinst.ini /etc/
WORKDIR /djangonoguero
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8000
```

requirements.txt:

```
pyodbc==3.0.10
django-mssql-backend==2.8.1
```

settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
  'pirineos': {
    'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
    'NAME': DB_PIRINEOS_NAME,
    'USER': DB_PIRINEOS_USER,
    'PASSWORD': DB_PIRINEOS_PASSWORD,
    'HOST': DB_PIRINEOS_HOST,
    'PORT': DB_PIRINEOS_PORT,
    'OPTIONS': {
      'driver': 'FreeTDS',
      'unicode_results': True,
      'driver_supports_utf8' : True,
      'extra_params': 'tds_version=8.0;',
    },
  },
}
```

odbcinst.ini:

```
[FreeTDS]
Description=FreeTDS Driver for Linux & MSSQL on Win32
Driver=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
UsageCount=1
```

Comment: Seems like a typo: `PORT={} database={};` - have you tried `PORT={};database={};` instead?

Comment: First cli command work well, the problem is with inspectdb command

Comment: Also, where do you get `tds_version=8.0` from? The highest TDS protocol version [FreeTDS supports](https://www.freetds.org/userguide/ChoosingTdsProtocol.html) is 7.4.

Comment: with `tds_version=7.4`the error persist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ADD odbcinst.ini /etc/
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y curl gnupg
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y unixodbc unixodbc-dev tdsodbc freetds-common freetds-bin freetds-dev postgresql python-scipy python-numpy python-pandas
RUN apt-get update && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -y install mssql-tools msodbcsql17
RUN echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile
RUN echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
RUN apt-get update
RUN mkdir /djangonoguero
COPY ./project /djangonoguero/
COPY ./requirements.txt /djangonoguero/
WORKDIR /djangonoguero
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8000
```

odbcinst.ini:

```
[FreeTDS]
Description=FreeTDS Driver
Driver=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
```

settings.py:

```
'pirineos': {
  'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
  'NAME': DB_PIRINEOS_NAME,
  'USER': DB_PIRINEOS_USER,
  'PASSWORD': DB_PIRINEOS_PASSWORD,
  'HOST': DB_PIRINEOS_HOST,
  'PORT': DB_PIRINEOS_PORT,
  'OPTIONS': {
    'driver': 'FreeTDS',
    'unicode_results': True,
    'host_is_server': True,
    'driver_supports_utf8': True,
    'extra_params': 'tds_version=7.4',
  },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I use image python:3.9.13-slim-buster, Django 3.2 and driver mssql-django

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9.13-slim-buster
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ADD odbcinst.ini /etc/
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y curl gnupg
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y unixodbc unixodbc-dev tdsodbc freetds-common freetds-bin freetds-dev postgresql python-scipy python-numpy python-pandas
RUN apt-get update && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -y install mssql-tools msodbcsql17
RUN echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile
RUN echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
RUN apt-get update
RUN pip install mssql-django
RUN mkdir /code
COPY . /code/
COPY ./requirements.txt /code/
WORKDIR /code
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8000
```

odbcinst.ini

```
[FreeTDS]
Description=FreeTDS Driver
Driver=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
```

requirements.txt

```
Django==3.2
django-environ==0.4.5
# psycopg2>=2.8.6,<2.9
uWSGI>=2.0.19.1,<2.1
Pillow >= 9.0.0,<10.0.0
```

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mssql',
        'HOST': os.environ.get('DB_HOST_SITO'),
        'NAME': os.environ.get('DB_NAME_SITO'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('DB_USER_SITO'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DB_PASS_SITO'),
        'PORT': os.environ.get('DB_PORT_SITO'),
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'FreeTDS',
            'unicode_results': True,
            'host_is_server': True,
            'driver_supports_utf8': True,
            'extra_params': 'tds_version=7.4',
        }
    },
}
```